# Wi-Fi problems - no connection with 2.4Gz network

Tags: wireless, hp, realtek

I have router Archer C60 v.2.0 (2.1.2 Build 20181227 rel.34229). There are set up two wi-fi network: 2.4Gz and 5Gz (with different SSID).
My HP notebook (Ubuntu 20.04 lts,  Realtek RTL8822BE 802.11ac PCIe Adapter) connects only with 5G wifi: when I try to connect to 2.4, it continiously asks for password (I tried to write password direclty to the saved network settings, but this did not helped). To 5.0Gz wifi network it connects successfully.

But, when I reboot to Win10, connection to 2,4Gz wifi network is established successfully.
That's why I think, that problem is only in Ubuntu setting, not in the router.
Would you be so kind to tell me, what should I check?

Comment: When dual-booting, disabling Windows' Fast Startup feature is a must. Try that and shutdown. Then boot Ubuntu and test again.

Comment: do you have bluetooth on in Ubuntu or in Windows?

Comment: @ChanganAuto 1) Windows Fast Startup is disabled (was disabled immidiately after Ubuntu has been installed).

2) Bluetooth is swiched off both in Windows and in Ubuntu.

Comment: Is the 2.4 gHz segment set to a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11 or to auto channel selec? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 auto channel selection is setted for 2.4gHz (and for 5gHz also is settted auto channel selection). Thanks for greeting.

Comment: Please try a fixed channel for both and tell us if there is any improvement.

Comment: @chili555 I tried to assign fixed chanels, but, unfortunately, it did not help.